# Flutter http / rest server not accessible from outside Android

Tags: android, flutter, rest, http, server

I'm working on a project in which I need to communicate between an Android device and a computer. To initiate a connection between these two device I thought using a Rest API mechanism with the following architecture :

- Rest server : Android Device by using https://pub.dev/packages/jaguar
- Rest client : my computer by using Python

My current flutter snippet looks like :

```dart
Jaguar server = Jaguar(port: 8080);
server.get("/", (context) => 'Hello');
await server.serve();
```

When accessing to "localhost:8080" from a web browser directly on my Android device, I get the "Hello" message but when trying to do the same thing from my computer (which is on the same network), I get a timeout error (on "192.168.0.10:8080").

It seems that my flutter (or my device) does not expose the web server to the rest of my network but I don't know why.. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: How do you try to access exactly the server from your computer's browser?

Comment: By trying to reach "192.168.0.10:8080"

Comment: Is your Jaguar server bound to localhost/127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Check firewall settings in your Android device, port 8080 should be open to serve incoming requests with TCP protocol.

Comment: @blackapps My server bound on 0.0.0.0 (default value)

Comment: @PeterKoltai how can I open this port ? By running adb tcpip 8080 ?

Comment: @arnaudm I don't know how to do it with Android, it is also possible that you can set it in Settings, I would look for network settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while, I found the solution. It's because since the API 28, Android blocks clear text traffic.

To solve this issue, we must override `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` like

```xml
<application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
...
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to bind the server to `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`.